# Multiple "On Delete Cascade" FKs from the same table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Trying to design a database and I have come into a serious issue. I have a table of nodes, and want to make a tree from these nodes.

A node can only be defined once, but can be used many times in a tree (all it's children will be the same as any other node of the same name)

To do this, I used a table called branches where a parent node is defined and a child node with FKs both to the node table.

My problem is that when a node is deleted I want the branch to be deleted as well, however I cannot add two ON DELETE CASCADE FKs to the table as SQL server won't let me as it thinks that the two Nodes (parent and child) could be the same and therefore wouldn't work so I get the error:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths
```

I know that this can be fixed using triggers, however if I add triggers I can't do actions before the delete and so have to do an INSTEAD of trigger, which then messes up my other FKs in the database and so I would pretty much have to write them for every FK in my large database.

I was wondering if there is a better way to design the database than I have done? Or will I just have to live with it and use triggers all over the place

Thanks

EDIT:

Designed as such:

```
Node {id, name, is_root}
Branch {id, node_parent_id, node_child_id}
```

Comment: Please post your table design.

Comment: I have posted the design

Comment: Deleting a parent (and any branches it participates in) will create orphaned nodes, no longer in your tree. Is such a design really desirable?

Comment: I realized this and it is handled in my code (bad I know). Another reason why I am asking for help with a better design...

Comment: So, that would indicate that you only really want the cascade on `node_child_id`, and attempting to delete the parent should produce an error, which it will if you have no action on `node_parent_id`.